# Should default model fields be set by the Form or the Model?

Tags: django, forms, models

Which option is best, 1 or 2?

1.

```
class TopicForm(forms.Form):

    name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    body = RichTextFormField(required=True)

    def save(self, request):
        t = models.Topic(user=request.user,
                         site=get_current_site(request),
                         name=self.cleaned_data['name'],
                         body=self.cleaned_data['body'])
        t.slug = slugify(self.name)
        t.body_html = seo.nofollow(seo.noindex(self.body))
        t.ip = utils.get_client_ip(request)
        t.save()
```

or 2.

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    ...   

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        self.body_html = seo.nofollow(seo.noindex(self.body))
        self.ip = utils.get_client_ip(request)
        super(Topic, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Perhaps someone with more knowledge could edit this question title to reflect the question. It is a bit ambiguous and does nto seem to reflect the question.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that the first version is only applied when modifying objects through the form, while the second is applied whenever the model is saved (though that is still a subset of all the ways in which database rows can be modified in Django). Even if you currently only create objects through forms, I think it's still a useful distinction to keep in mind.

It looks to me like a mixture of the two makes sense in your case. A `slug` is something that you will always want to set based on `name` - that is, it's inherent to the model itself. On the other hand, the idea of a `client_ip` seems inexorably tied to the notion of creating an object with a form via a web request.

Of course, you are in a better position to know about the specifics of this model, but that is the general way I would approach the question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If this should be applied to every models, then it is better in the model. It will assure you that every `Topic` object will have correct values, even those you are edited from the admin interface.

The form should be use only to check data from the user and the model is appropriate to automatize this kind of task (generate data before saving the object). Be careful, this shouldn't raise Exception or invalidate data however.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would prefer the second option. The model should define the business logic too, while forms should just handle user I/O. This way your application will keep consistent even if used in a programmatic way (imported and called from other code).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt use 2. its better to use a signal like pre-save or post-save

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/

```
    @receiver(pre_save, sender=Topic)
    def topic_pre_save_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.slug = slugify(self.name)
        instance.body_html = seo.nofollow(seo.noindex(self.body))
        instance.ip = utils.get_client_ip(request)
```